# Using Pylab to create a plot of a line and then getting the rasterized data from the line

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, matplotlib

I am trying to get the rasterized line data from a pylab plot function. My code is like so:

```
fitfunc = lambda p, x: p[0] + p[1] * sin(2 * pi * x / data[head[0]].size + p[2])
errfunc = lambda p, x, y: fitfunc(p, x) - y

data = np.genfromtxt(dataFileName, dtype=None, delimiter='\t', names=True)

xAxisSeries =linspace(0., data[head[0]].max(), data[head[0]].size)

p0 = [489., 1000., 9000.] # Initial guess for the parameters
p1, success = optimize.leastsq(errfunc, p0[:], args=(xAxisSeries, data[head[1]]))

time = linspace(xAxisSeries.min(), xAxisSeries.max(), 1000)

plotinfo = plot(time, fitfunc(p1, time), 'r-')
```

I want to get the x and y line data from plotinfo. When I use "type(plotinfo)," plotinfo is a list, but when using "print plotinfo," it is a 2dlist object.

Comment: Isn't `(time,fitfunc(p1,time))` the `(x,y)` data you are looking for? Or do you want it in the pixel coordinates of the pylab figure? or something else?

Comment: If i understand you correctly, you want the interpoataled data?

Comment: You can get everypoint you want from your function, why use interpolation? If you want interpolation use : np.interp(new_x, old_x, old_y)

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N=4
x=np.linspace(0, 10, N)
y=np.cumsum(np.random.random(N) - 0.5)
line=plt.plot(x,y)[0]
path=line._path
```

These are the original (x,y) data points:

```
print(path.vertices)
# [[  0.           0.08426592]
#  [  3.33333333   0.14204252]
#  [  6.66666667   0.41860647]
#  [ 10.           0.22516175]]
```

Here we (linearly) interpolate to find additional points. You can increase the argument to `path.interpolated` to find more interpolated points between the original points.

```
path2=path.interpolated(2)
print(path2.vertices)
# [[  0.           0.08426592]
#  [  1.66666667   0.11315422]
#  [  3.33333333   0.14204252]
#  [  5.           0.2803245 ]
#  [  6.66666667   0.41860647]
#  [  8.33333333   0.32188411]
#  [ 10.           0.22516175]]
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the values for 0,1,2,3...to 10? nevermind, I just re-read your post. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you want the interpolated values at particular points, I would use tillsten's idea: `y2=np.interp(range(11),x,y)`. Using this, no matplotlib is necessary.

Comment: he just can use fitfunc(p1, range(11)).